# After I create an account on a site take me back to the page I was on rather than the main page

Tags: feature-request, login, new-users

### Background

By far the number 1 reason I join a stack exchange site is because I've seen an existing question/answer that is excellent and I want to upvote it. When attempting to upvote it this brings up the familiar "Thanks for your feedback, you need to login” page.

> [image]

I then signup using Stack Exchange (so far so good) however; this then dumps me back on the sites main page. I then attempt to use the back button to get back to my original page but the login page is one of those instant redirects that foils the back button.

> `https://SITEURL/users/login-add` is an insta-redirect

So eventually I use my internet history to re-find the page, or give up, depending on how much I cared about the original question.

### Feature Request

Where it is necessary to create a new user to perform an action return me to the page I was on once creation of a new user is complete.

This may not be possible for all OpenID providers but it would be nice if at least StackExchange's provider did this.

Comment: Try holding down the left mouse button or right clicking on the Back button in your browser, it gives you a dropdown of your recent history. Very useful with instant redirects.

Comment: @Stijn Nice! Certainly makes it a little less angering

Comment: @RichardTingle, are you on Safari? I've actually noticed this, too, but I don't think it happens to everyone.

Comment: @Jaydles No, I'm on firefox (on windows 7)

Comment: This already happens with existing-user login (if your referer *[sic]* header is okay).