# Creating an account doesn't redirect me back to where I was

Tags: feature-request, login, user-accounts

This is somewhat related to this question: ["After I create an account on a site take me back to the page I was on rather than the main page"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224251/after-i-create-an-account-on-a-site-take-me-back-to-the-page-i-was-on-rather-tha)

If I am on a community's Meta site and I do **not** have an account yet for the community, when I click "Ask a question" I am redirected to the parent community to create my account. Upon completing my account creation though, I am redirected not back to where I wanted to go ("Ask A Question"), the main community's homepage.

It would be nice if login / signup redirections would take you back to where you started.

Comment: This is a good suggestion but it's mostly a duplicate, as you acknowledged. Is there a reason for submitting it as a new question rather than as just a comment on that other question or rather than just quietly upvoting that question or one of its comments? (I'm just trying to understand how things work around here, especially after getting roundly downvoted for a question that I didn't even want to ask but I didn't have enough rep to just quietly upvote a comment I liked on an existing question.)

Comment: Note the diamond. Read the user's profile. It's SE employee, developer, and this means he's going to change this behavior.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well I hope so. I also post it here so I don't forget about it. I recently had to create a number of community accounts to test something out and this particular workflow frustrated me.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, I did already see that information, but that information still doesn't explain why a new question was submitted versus a quiet upvote or a somewhat quiet comment on an existing question.

Comment: @JonFreed I could have done what you suggested. Personally I didn't feel the other post I shared wasn't an exact match of my particular problem. If people feel this is a duplicate, that's fine. Close and redirect to the other question. No hard feelings. :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!  I swear I am not trying to be difficult. I'm just trying to understand, and I'm certainly not alone in my confusion.  Thanks

Comment: I really think the title is more [tag:bug] than [tag:feature-request]. The body could go either way, however.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused, as SE developer can't you, well, fix it yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Hm. So, a couple issues here.

First of all, I broadly agree that we should return you back to where you came from. Practically, however, it's a bit complicated.

In no particular order...

1. We preserve (or at least should - if we don't, that's a bug) return url when signing up/logging in with Google, Facebook, etc. (Basically any provider that doesn't take you out of the in-website flow.)
2. When it comes to signing up with email/password, there's a necessary email confirmation step. That tends to throw a wrench into the proceedings. As a compromise, we redirect to /tour to at least put you somewhere sane-adjacent  in a sign-up flow. (Redirecting back *should* work for logging in with email/password, though. If it doesn't, that's a bug.)
3. The specific case you describe is probably one of the worst we have because you can't actually post on a child meta with a brand new 1-rep account, so redirecting back there is ultimately not helpful. (But it would be helpful if you got the association bonus or if you were logging into an existing account that has the necessary rep to participate on meta.)
4. There is currently an issue where if you're logged in, visit a child meta where you don't have a profile, and click "join" in the top bar, you'll actually hit a 404. That's obviously a bug, on my list of things to fix hopefully this week.
5. Everything is further complicated by a user choosing to sign up/log in with a question or an answer already typed up (most sites do not require logging in to ask questions). I believe we try to preserve their post and make it at the end of the flow, but it's possibly broken in some scenarios (such as signing up with email/password). I'm not 100% sure.

Trying to maintain consistency in this behaviour has been nightmarish. I'm happy to make improvements (I believe login still falls under my jurisdiction by the "you touched it last, so good luck" definition), but I currently lack the time to put into coming up with something coherent and re-testing all the things.

Which brings me to this question: can you add more detail into your request? Which site were you on? What provider did you use? Did you actually sign up or did you log in? Might just be a bug here that I can fix pretty quickly. :)